# Load Historical data to teradata temporal table

Tags: teradata, temporal, temporal-database

I have a task to load existing SQL Server table to Teradata temporal table. Existing table is a type 2 table and has many versions of record. I need to load them into teradata temporal table. I am planning to load version 1 1st and then update all other versions one by one. 
Difficulties i am having is that in existing table every record has start time and end time. I need to update that time in teradata temporal table as validity.

1st I am trying to insert and while insert i am not able to insert end time as less than current time. It report error as "Check constraint violation". Below is sample piece of code for creating table and inserting.

I am yet to test updates as not able to do 1st step.

```
CREATE multiset TABLE EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test
(
    ID INTEGER,
    Validity PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(3)) NOT NULL AS VALIDTIME
);

insert into EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test(id,Validity) values(
1,period(cast('1996-01-20 05.00.00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3)), cast('2016-06-23 21.52.20.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))))
--this pass as 2016 is greater than current date
insert into EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test(id,Validity) values(
1,period(cast('1996-01-20 05.00.00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3)), cast('2015-06-23 21.52.20.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))))
--This fails as i m trying to give end time less than current date.
```

Is there anyway to give end time as less than current date. any way to disable this constraint for time and then enable.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: use Sequnce VT modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert history rows you should use Sequnce Valid Time Modifier...

Eg :

```
SEQUENCED VALIDTIME
insert into EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test(id,Validity) values(
1,period(cast('1996-01-20 05.00.00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3)), cast('2015-06-23 21.52.20.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))));
```

Comment: Hi @anwaar_hell that worked to insert a single row at a time. But i have to insert multiple row using insert-select statement.  When i tried statements as below I git another error. Can you please advise how to to fix this: sequenced validtime
    insert into EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test(id,Validity) 
    select id, period(cast('1996-01-20 05.00.00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3)), cast('2015-06-23 21.52.20.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))) 
    from EDW_T.edw_Contracts_History_Test
    --ValidTime column name is invalid in the column list for a sequenced insert-select statement.  thanks for your help

Comment: Hi I was able to find the solution. we need to use merge instead of insert-select statement. Got help from below link [merge update Temporal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171074/merge-update-temporal?rq=1)

Comment: I have another issue in next step. I have 3 versions of records. e.g. 1st one 1/1/10-1/1/11. I am able to insert 1st version using merge. 2nd version is from 1/1/11-1/1/14. If i try to do merge and update validity(period column) using non sequenced then teradata update 1st records itself. Maybe because it turn off temporal feature. but i missed history. so i tried to update without using  non sequenced. Problem with that is query doesn't find data in table and say as 0 rows updated. That must be because it read only current record. Is there any way i can load all three versions.

Comment: This question was further discussed and answered in below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613288/historical-data-load-from-sql-to-teradata-temporal-table)